# Javascript: jQuery $(this) inside map() function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replicate the $(this) jQuery selector inside a pure javascript map() function.
I want to listen onclick of an li and apply a background image to that specific li.

Here's my code but here, 'this' does not return the clicked li element:

```
var squares = document.getElementsByClassName('box'); //returns an HTML Collection of 9 lis

           function myEvent(event) {
              squares = Array.prototype.slice.call(squares); //converts HTML collection to an Array
                squares.map(function(x, index) {

                  if (event.type === "click") {
                   this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/' + app.imagePath() + '.svg)';
                  }

                }, this);
              }
  squares.addEventListener("click", myEvent(), false);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you describe the specific error that you are having, instead of "not working" type scenarios?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: how are you binding the click event to the li?

Comment: addEventListener does not solve the problem, I need to return the li that was clicked on...

Comment: `squares.addEventListener("click", myEvent(), false);` you are executing `myEvent` here instead of passing it `squares.addEventListener("click", myEvent, false);` if you still have issues with `this`, add `console.log(...)` and `debugger` into your code to inspect your `this` and `event` objects as needed.

Answer (score 3):

`squares` is a list of elements (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You need to loop the results:

```
for(var i =0; i< squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].addEventListener("click", myEvent, false);
}
```

also you pass a function ref, do not pass the result of the function (remove the brackets after `myEvent` in the `addEventListener`)

Also as per zer00ne awnser, all the event function needs to do is:

```
function myEvent(event) {
    this.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/' + app.imagePath() + '.svg)';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please test this:

Instead of this:

```
this.style.backgroundImage....
```

Use this:

```
event.target.style.backgroundImage
```

and the last this so change that to event.atrget

Comment: Thank you brother, but please so pay attention to Andrew's answer. That is your another problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation by registering a click event on the parent of all of those elements. Details are commented in Snippet. It just involves **ONE** eventListener and it will cover **ALL** the clickable elements you want.

**SNIPPET**

```js
var base = document.getElementById('base');

// When base is clicked...
base.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  /* When an event fires it goes down from base...
  || to the very bottom element which is any of ..
  || the squares. The one that's clicked at the...
  || bottom is called event.target. It's determined...
  || by comparing the other elements in the event...
  || chain. All elements that are in the event chain...
  || are refered by the event.currentTarget property
  */
  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {
    var target = event.target;
    target.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://imgh.us/Lenna.png)';
    target.style.backgroundSize = 'contain';
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id='base'>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</section>
```